# pyotp.TOTP code doesn't match authenticator code

Tags: python, authentication, totp

I'm trying to use python's support for TOTP to programmatically get the MFA/2FA code available in the Microsoft authenticator application. My code looks like this:

```
import pyotp
import base64
secret = "mysecretkeyhere".encode( "UTF-8" )
b32Secret = base64.b32encode( secret )
totp = pyotp.TOTP( b32Secret ).now()
print( totp )
```

The `mysecretkeyhere` is from scanning the QR code/key, and is of the format

"otpauth://totp/*namehere*?secret=*16digitsecrethere*&issue=*issuerhere*&algorithm=SHA1&digits=6"

When I run this code segment and compare with the 6-digit code in my authenticator application, the generated code in my application and the authenticator app don't agree. The codes don't overlap on a time-delay, either (tested with a while loop that does the bottom two lines repeatedly).

Any suggestions as to how to get the TOTP function to return the same code that's in my authenticator app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently on another issue with pyotp - and so found your problem.

You have a secret, that is an OTP-URI which should simply be parsed. [According to documentation](https://pyauth.github.io/pyotp/):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyotp

otp_uri = 'otpauth://totp/namehere?secret=16digitsecrethere&issue=issuerhere&algorithm=SHA1&digits=6'
otp     = pyotp.parse_uri( otp_uri )

print( otp.now() )
```

Hope that still supports your needs =)
Best
macwinnie

Comment: This answer was perfect, issuer needed removing from the URI, but otherwise got me up and running!

Comment: You're welcome, @GDev – the URI is generated by your OTP provider and thus can contain different partials =)